# Access error 2427: You entered an expression that has no value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form, and am counting the number of records in a subform. Sometimes the subform is empty, which I'd like to check for, but it throws

```
Run-time error '2427': You entered an expression that has no value
```

It's obvious why this error is happening, but less obvious is how to work around it. This is the code causing the error. MainTableComboBox.Value contains RecordID.

```
DCount("*", "[SubFormTable]", "[SubFormTable].[RecordID] = " & MainTableTextBox.Value)
```

I've tried the following but it still errors out.

- Using `If(IsError(Dcount...)) then (do stuff)`
- [Checking that the number of records is larger than zero](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cbe20928-a121-4709-a7c3-d8952973242f/runtime-error-2455-you-entered-an-expression-that-has-an-invalid-reference-to-the-property?forum=accessdev)
- [Nested Nothing, IfNull, and IfEmpty statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531146/2427-you-entered-an-expression-that-has-no-value)
- [Using an error handler](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26812093/Error-handling-for-'Runtime-error-2427'-in-MS-Access.html)

What other ways exist to get around this error?

Comment: Your DCount statement shouldn't throw this error. Can you show your actual code and how you call / use it?

Comment: @Andre That's the actual code. For debugging purposes, I have it run inside a MsgBox() when I click a button on the form. The form is linked to the subform on RecordID and they both use different tables: the form uses `Customers` and the subform uses `Products`. A customer may or may not have any products listed.

Comment: @HansUp When I have records in the subform, it shows -1 when I click the button. When I have no records in the subform, it shows the error and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Whoops, I checked the MainTable box and it's actually a text box. Its ControlSource is RecordID.

Comment: I included `Option Explicit` and Christopher's answer below, and it worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could set a recordset equal to the subform datasource and use `IF rs.EOF = True Then` to see if there are records to show before running your dcount function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793097/access-vba-how-to-test-if-recordset-is-empty-isnull) question for more information.

Comment: Ah, that did it, thanks. I defined the RecordSets as in your linked question, then used `If rs.BOF = True And rs.EOF = True Then (empty subform message) Else DCount() End If`. It seems that to test for an empty table I only need BOF *or* EOF, and not both. Is there any case where this is not true?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj I can't think of a situation that would cause an issue. I'm pretty new to using recordsets in general, so I'm probably not much help. AFAIK after setting `rs`, it moves to Record 1 if not null, or to `BOF` and `EOF` if it is null. This article has helped me wrap my head around `rs` and may help answer your question: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners. I see a lot of examples using `AND` and `OR` online, I'm just not sure why they differ.

Comment: Checking for .BOF **and** .EOF is cargo cult programming and is actually never needed. You either move forward in a recordset, or have just opened it, then use `.EOF`. You move backward, use `.BOF`.

Comment: @Andre Not sure how well I understood your point.  Do you call `Not (.BOF And .EOF)` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37052403/77335) cargo cult programming?

Comment: @HansUp: Um, well, yes. After opening a recordset, it either has at least one record, or not. If not, `.EOF` will always be true, so checking additionally for `.BOF` is simply unnecessary.

Comment: When you apply that label so broadly, then [Dim dbs As DAO.Database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34969410/77335) is "cargo cult programming" (per your criterion) since the DAO prefix is simply unnecessary there.