# VBA - Run Time Error 3271 using DAO object

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I'm trying to update a SQL server database using `DAO.QueryDef` and a local `Append` query in Microsoft Access. Some of my fields that are being updated contain very long strings (anywhere from `0` to upwards of `700` characters).

When the string length is in the range from `0` to `255` characters, I have no problem passing it into my query and updating the respective tables. However when they exceed `255` characters, I receive the following run-time error:

[image: VBA Run-time error 3271]

I have been using a [random string generator website](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/randomization-tools/random-string-generator/) to create and test strings with varying lengths. I have also checked my database for the column data types and they are all `NVARCHAR(MAX)` where they need to be. Microsoft Access is showing the same respective columns with the data type `Long text`.

See below for my code snippet:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb

If Not IsNull(cmbboxFileNameLogic) Then
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryUpdateFile")

    qdf.Parameters("FileName").Value = txtboxUpdateConversionName.Value
    qdf.Parameters("ZipFileName").Value = txtboxZipFileNameLogic.Value
    qdf.Parameters("OutputFormat").Value = txtboxOutputFormat.Value
    qdf.Parameters("Delimeter").Value = txtboxDelimeter.Value
    qdf.Parameters("DestinationLocation").Value = txtboxDestinationLocation.Value
    qdf.Parameters("DeliveryMechinism").Value = txtboxDeliveryMechinism.Value
    qdf.Parameters("Note").Value = txtboxOutputFileInfoNotes.Value
    qdf.Parameters("Criteria").Value = txtboxOutputFileInfoCriteria.Value
    qdf.Parameters("CustomListKey").Value = txtboxCustomListKey.Value
    qdf.Parameters("ExcludeCustomListKey").Value = txtboxExcludeCustomListKey.Value
    qdf.Parameters("NewspaperFlag").Value = chkNewsPaperFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("WebsiteFlag").Value = chkWebsiteFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("MarketingFlag").Value = chkProfessionalMarketingFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("PrintFlag").Value = chkProfessionalPrintFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("WebsiteFlag").Value = chkWebsiteFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("BrokerDealerFlag").Value = chkBrokerDealerFlag.Value
    qdf.Parameters("ActiveOnly").Value = chkActiveOnly.Value
    qdf.Parameters("OutputFormatting").Value = txtboxFileFormatting.Value
    qdf.Parameters("Header").Value = txtboxHeader.Value
    qdf.Parameters("Footer").Value = txtboxFooter.Value
    qdf.Parameters("SQLStatement").Value = txtboxSQLStatement.Value
    qdf.Parameters("OrderBy").Value = txtboxOrderBy.Value
    qdf.Parameters("FileID").Value = cmbboxFileNameLogic.Value

    qdf.Execute dbSeeChanges
    qdf.Close

    lblOutputFileInfoAction.Caption = "File successfully updated"
    lblOutputFileInfoAction.Visible = True

Else
    -- Insert new values
End If
```

Query Definition:

```
UPDATE myTableNameGoesHere SET fldFileNameLogic = [FileName], 
fldZipFileNameLogic = [ZipFileName],fldOutputFormat = [OutputFormat],
fldDelimeter = [Delimeter], 
fldDestinationLocation = [DestinationLocation], fldDeliveryMechinism = [DeliveryMechinism], 
fldNote = [Note], fldCriteria = [Criteria], fldCustomListKey = [CustomListKey],
fldExcludeCustomListKey = [ExcludeCustomListKey], fldNewspaperFlag = [NewspaperFlag], 
fldProfessionalWebsiteFlag = [WebsiteFlag], fldProfessionalMarketingFlag = [MarketingFlag], 
fldProfessionalPrintFlag = [PrintFlag], fldWebsiteFlag = [WebsiteFlag], 
fldBrokerDealerFlag = [BrokerDealerFlag], fldActiveOnly = [ActiveOnly], 
fldFileOutputFormatting = [OutputFormatting], fldHeader = [Header], 
fldFooter = [Footer], fldSQLStatement = [SQLStatement], fldOrderBy = [OrderBy]
WHERE [fldFileID] = [FileID];
```

Comment: Assuming `qryUpdateFile` is a local Access object, does a plain vanilla `INSERT` statement with long texts work, typed into the SQL view of a new query? (Without using VBA objects)

Comment: @Leviathan Yes this had worked before. I did have to escape certain characters such as `'` and `"` which was a pain. It's also open to SQL injection which is why I have chosen to revise my old code and use parameterized queries. `qryUpdateFile` is a local access object, I am not calling any SQL stored procs or anything for now.

Comment: Can you add the full SQL of `qryUpdateFile` (including the PARAMETERS section) to your question?

Comment: Well, this might be DAO not correctly interpreting text fields with more than 255 characters length. What does `qdf.Fields("ProblematicField").Size` return? And as what type does the querydef interpret this field? (`qdf.Fields("ProblematicField").Type`)

Comment: @Andre I have updated my OP to include the full SQL statement

Comment: @Leviathan My usage is probably wrong because I'm getting a `Item not found in this collection`. I'm just declaring an integer and assigning it like so: `fieldSize = qdf.Fields("SQLStatement").Size`. I have a breakpoint set which breaks with the exception.

Comment: `dbs.QueryDefs("qryUpdateFile")` returns a querydef object based on the Acces object "qryUpdateFile". `dbs.QueryDefs("qryUpdateFile").Fields("fldFileNameLogic")` returns a field object based on the field "fldFileNameLogic" in "qryUpdateFile". You have to specify the field name, not an SQL statement.

Comment: There is no `PARAMETERS` statement in the update query. How are you defining them? Please also break lines in query to avoid horizontal scrolling. Also what line does debugger highlight?

Comment: @Parfait I have fixed the horizontal scrolling issue. I have not defined any `PARAMETERS` within the query itself. This was my first time trying to figure out this concept in MS Access and I think I misunderstood how they should be set up. The debugger in VBA will highlight any line in which a parameter length is over 255 characters. For example, if I am updating the field `Note` and the textbox containing the text to update is `1000` characters long, the exception will be thrown there.

Comment: @Leviathan My parameter, `SQLStatement`, is not an actual SQL statement that is used for anything. It is simply just a text field that can be very large. It should have been `fldSqlStatement` according to your response. `fldFileNameLogic` is a column inside my database and `FileNameLogic` is the value I am passing into the query.

Comment: So now, what do `qdf.Fields("fldFileNameLogic ").Size` and `qdf.Fields("fldFileNameLogic ").Type` return?

Comment: @Leviathan I'm receiving the same `Item not found in this collection` error. http://i.imgur.com/zHHXFVY.jpg

Comment: But there *is* a field named `fldFileNameLogic` in `qryUpdateFile`, right? Btw., `test1` and `test2` cannot be objects in the code from the screenshot. Long should be ok, Variant will definetely work.

Comment: @Leviathan That is correct. I have a table `tblFile` with a column `fldFileNameLogic` - this contains the name of a file. This field should be the **first** field in my query `qryUpdateFile`.

Comment: Strange... however, this probably isn't even important, seeing HansUp's answer. If you think otherwise, we can still follow up on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're facing a limitation of Access SQL text parameters.  They can not accommodate string values longer than 255 characters.

Here is a simple example which demonstrates the problem.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strUpdate As String
Dim strLongString As String
strLongString = String(300, "x")
strUpdate = "UPDATE tblFoo SET memo_field = [pLongString] WHERE id=2;"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)
qdf.Parameters("pLongString").Value = strLongString
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

That code triggers error #3271, *"Invalid property value."* ... the same error you're seeing.

If I change the `UPDATE` statement to include a `PARAMETERS` clause like this ...

```vb
strUpdate = "PARAMETERS [pLongString] LongText;" & vbCrLf & _
    "UPDATE tblFoo SET memo_field = [pLongString] WHERE id=2;"
```

... the outcome is still error #3271.

I don't believe there is any way to overcome that Access SQL limitation.

So if the length of your text parameter value is greater than 255 characters, you need a different method.

A `DAO.Recordset` approach is a simple alternative to store long text strings in a field.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect
strSelect = "SELECT id, memo_field FROM tblFoo WHERE id=2;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
With rs
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .Edit
        !memo_field.Value = strLongString
        .Update
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

[DAO Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn124645.aspx) — [Recordset object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn125237.aspx)

Comment: I will most likely have to take this route. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Makes you wonder why `LongText` is a valid parameter data type at all.

Comment: I wondered about that, too, @Andre.  But I still don't see where `LongText` is useful.  I think it would be great if someone can tell us.  :-)  In the meantime, at least `DAO.Recordset.Edit` works.  ;-)

Comment: @Andre It seems that [ADO doesn't have this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40459293/111794).

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly define the query parameters, at least those with LongText data type. Otherwise Access has to guess their data type.

You can do this in the query design editor, click on the "Parameters" button.

Or in SQL view, creating a [PARAMETERS clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```sql
PARAMETERS [parLongString] LongText;
UPDATE myTable
SET LongString = [parLongString]
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [HansUp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052403/111794), it seems that ADO doesn't have this issue.

Add a reference (**Tools -> References...**) to the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** library (choose the highest version; on my machine it's 6.1).

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
cmd.CommandText = "qryUpdateFile"

'the rest of the parameter values need to be included in the array
'omitted for brevity
cmd.Execute , Array(txtboxUpdateConversionName.Value, txtboxZipFileNameLogic.Value)
```

[ADO Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249084.aspx)

- [Command object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249590.aspx)
- [Command.Execute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj248785.aspx)