# INSERT INTO statement in Access is cutting off at 255 characters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form in Access where users are able to type information in a textbox and hit a button that would run an INSERT INTO statement. Even though I have formatted some of my data types to be Long Texts I'm still getting a run-time error 3271. I would like the user to be able to type more than 255 character into the textbox in the form and have that data to insert a new row in my table:

```
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "INSERT INTO AllProjects (ProjectNumber, ProjectTitle, Description, Department, Priority, Status, [Create Date], [% Complete], [Update Notes], Leader, [Initial Target Date], [Complete Date], Category, Feedback, [Strategic Initiatives], Subcategory, [Internal/External], [Case #], Alloy, Goals, Customer, [Market Segment], [Result of Corrective Action], [Initiator], [Representative / PM / CSA], [Team Memebers], [FQA Needed], [WON / LOST / DUNNO]) VALUES (@prjnum, @title, @description, @dept, @prior, @status, @createdate, @ctlcomp, @notes, @lead, @targdate, @compdate, @cat, @feedback, @initiatives, @sub, @internal, @case, @alloy, @goals, @customer, @mktseg, @result, @initiat, @rep, @team, @FQA, @wonloss)")
    qdf.Parameters("@prjnum").Value = ProjectNumber
    qdf.Parameters("@title").Value = Me.Title
    qdf.Parameters("@description").Value = Me.Description
    qdf.Parameters("@dept").Value = Me.Department
    qdf.Parameters("@prior").Value = Me.Priority
    qdf.Parameters("@status").Value = Me.Status
    qdf.Parameters("@createdate").Value = Me.Create_Date
    qdf.Parameters("@ctlcomp").Value = Me.Ctl__Complete
    qdf.Parameters("@notes").Value = Me.Update_Notes
    qdf.Parameters("@lead").Value = Me.Leader
    qdf.Parameters("@targdate").Value = Me.Target_Date
    qdf.Parameters("@compdate").Value = Me.Complete_Date
    qdf.Parameters("@cat").Value = Me.Category
    qdf.Parameters("@feedback").Value = Me.Feedback
    qdf.Parameters("@initiatives").Value = Me.Strategic_Initiatives
    qdf.Parameters("@sub").Value = Me.Sub
    qdf.Parameters("@internal").Value = Me.Internal
    qdf.Parameters("@case").Value = Me.Case
    qdf.Parameters("@alloy").Value = Me.Alloy
    qdf.Parameters("@goals").Value = Me.Goals
    qdf.Parameters("@customer").Value = Me.Customer
    qdf.Parameters("@mktseg").Value = Me.Market_Segment
    qdf.Parameters("@result").Value = Me.result
    qdf.Parameters("@initiat").Value = Me.Initiator
    qdf.Parameters("@rep").Value = Me.RepresentativePMCSA
    qdf.Parameters("@team").Value = Me.TeamMembers
    qdf.Parameters("@FQA").Value = Me.FQANeeded
    qdf.Parameters("@wonloss").Value = Me.WonLostDunno
    qdf.Execute
```

Comment: tried using the Memo field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Run Time Error 3271 using DAO object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049626/vba-run-time-error-3271-using-dao-object)

Comment: @ZevSpitz I've seen this. I'm new to this however, could you break it down more so I understand how to implement this solution to my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by inserting the record with DAO objects, instead of executing an SQL statement. Something like this:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = cdb.OpenRecordset("AllProjects")
With rs
    .AddNew
    !ProjectNumber = ProjectNumber
    !ProjectTitle = ProjectTitle
    '...
    .Update
End With
```

[DAO Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn124645.aspx) — [Recordset object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn125237.aspx)

---

It seems that ADO doesn't have this issue, even when executing SQL statements.

You'll need to add a reference (**Tools -> References...**) to the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** library (choose the highest version; on my machine it's 6.1).

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
'query shortened for brevity
cmd.CommandText = _
    "INSERT INTO AllProjects (ProjectNumber, ProjectTitle, Description) " & _
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cmd.Execute , Array(ProjectNumber, Me.Title, Me.Description)
```

[ADO Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249084.aspx)

- [Command object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249590.aspx)
- [Command.Execute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj248785.aspx)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the extra help.

Comment: @MekenzieBuhr Using ADO (an alternate library that can be used to connect to Access databases) seems to work with SQL. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

for a text field in access, maximum limit is 255 characters. you will not be able to insert more than 255 characters. look at [max allowed characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854) and use as per requirement. try using a Memo field (Number of characters in a Memo field 65,535.)

Comment: Number of characters in a Text field: 255
Number of characters in a Memo field: 65,535 when entering data through the user interface;1 gigabyte of character storage when entering data programmatically

Comment: I'm using Access 2016 so yes I have the data type set to "Long Text" which is the same as a Memo field now [The-Memo-data-type-is-now-called-Long-Text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/The-Memo-data-type-is-now-called-Long-Text-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5)

Comment: @GhostDeveloper This did not fix my problem I already had the field set to memo/long text.

Comment: can you please post the error details (error text + code)?