# How can I pass a LONGTEXT Parameter using DAO?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am tying to pass a userform textbox of more than 255 characters to a MS Access field through a parameter. I am unable to do so given the length of characters in my textbox, which generates a runtime error. I would like to avoid writing an SQL Statement directly in my macro. Is there any way around this restriction without using ADO?

**CODE**

```vb
Sub updateRecord()

Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef


Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to PBS Database......"
Set db = OpenDatabase("Z:\UBPB CRM Project\pbsbackup.mdb")
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("addclient")


Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Client Data to PBS server...."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

    qdf!pbsbranch = Sheet4.Range("A2")
    qdf!pbsclient = addnewClient.client
    qdf!pbspriority = addnewClient.priority_
    qdf!pbssource = addnewClient.priority
    qdf!pbscontact = addnewClient.contact
    qdf!pbsresult = addnewClient.result
    qdf!pbsnextsteps = addnewClient.segmentType
    qdf!pbsattempts = addnewClient.Label11
    qdf!pbsnotes = addnewClient.notes


qdf.Execute dbFailOnError


qdf.Close
db.Close
Application.StatusBar = "Upload Successful!"

Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Run Time Error 3271 using DAO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049626/vba-run-time-error-3271-using-dao-object)

Comment: You can't with DAO.