# Access vba code to update a field with a text that is an html-code

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, sql-update

i have made a code that makes a text and shows that txt through a msgbox.
Now i want this txt as well in a table, because i need others to copy this txt and paste it somewhere else.

In the table i made a memofield txt_GER for the german txt.

In the code i wrote:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE Table SET txt_GER=" & txt & " WHERE ID=" & rs.Fields("Id"))
```

When i try to run this code i get this message:
Runtime error 3075:
Syntaxiserror (missing operator) in query-expression

```
<B>xxx</B><ul class="yyy"><li>zzz<li>
```

I want this txt including the html-codes into this field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters instead, e.g.:

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "update Table set txt_GER=@txt where ID=@id")
    .Parameters(0) = txt
    .Parameters(1) = rs.Fields("Id")
    .Execute
End With
```

With your current code, the string delimiters present in the value held by your `txt` variable are terminating the SQL statement prematurely.

Comment: I never worked with 'with' or with createquerydef. I now get a failure message on Parameters(0) --> 3271 --> google learned me it has probably to do with the length of the text exceeding 255 characters. So I should define the parameters in the query?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049626/vba-run-time-error-3271-using-dao-object

Comment: As HansUp showed in the linked question, this doesn't work for > 255 chars. You can either use `Recordset.Edit` or your original method, using Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL. It will safely encapsulate `txt`. @Cleo